# Virtual Hosts Directing to Another URL

Tags: apache2

I have multiple vhosts setup in apache2.  3 hosts to be exact. site1, site2, dev1. When I enable the dev1.conf it causes site2.com to show dev1.com.  These are WordPress installs. site1.com shows as expected.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.site1.com
    ServerAlias dev.site1.com
    Redirect / https://dev.site1.com/
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin admin@domain1.com
ServerName dev.dev1.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/dev/
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /cloudflare/dev.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /cloudflare/dev.key

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev.com_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev.com_access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/dev/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>


</VirtualHost>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
    Redirect / https://www.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2/

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin ironvikingsmc.it@gmail.com
ServerName www.site2.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/site2/
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /cloudflare/site2.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /cloudflare/site2.key

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site2.com_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site2.com_access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/site2/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
</Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried to edit the vhosts and I also added `define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' ); define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );` to the configs of each root.

Comment: Use the CLI `curl` and run this command. `curl -v -L http://www.site2.com`. Edit your post and show the command and output. If you have not used curl before, spend some time understanding the HTTP request and response. Very useful command for debugging problems.